# Alloy Analyzer: What influences the number of available solutions

Tags: alloy

I'm currently trying to figure out, how the maximum number of computed solutions is related to the A4Options and other configuration properties (I use the API).

The strange thing is that with increasing scope the number of available solutions do not change. They are constant no matter if I set the scope limit to 30 or 100 elements or any other number.

If I modify the amount of symmetry breaking (A4Options.symmetrie) I get tons of solutions but the influence of the symmetrie option is rather unclear to me.

**My question is: Does anybody know how to make sure that I'm able to generate ALL possible solutions?**

Please let me know if you need further details!

Thank you very much in advance,
LostSpirit

Comment: Ok, I figured out that the Command properties "bitwidth" and "maxseq" are very important. I used the default values (4 and 7). I also read that these two parameters restrict the set of integers that are generated. Since I have a constraint which says that each integer may only be assigned once, using the standard configuration, I get min(2^bitwidth,maxSeq) integers, right?

Comment: It seems that would be the case, but note that bitwidth is for instantiated integers, while maxseq is the maximum length of sequences that you have (declared with _seq_, see [seq](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/seq.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are increasing the scope but the number of solutions stays the same, most probably your model is implicitly imposing those limitations (e.g. with singleton signatures).

Note that, if that is the case, then it is expected that changing symmetry breaking still changes the number of solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I've started with a rather simple model. There is only one signature without the singleton constraint. And this is included in the scope, i.e. I want to create a set of elements following this signature.

Comment: The elements have an integer property. An integer value can be assigned only once (disj). The lowest number is 0 and the highest is equal to the number of elements in the model.
So I would expect that I get the complete set of possible configurations. Since it is a finite set.

Comment: Indeed, so `bitwidth` represents the integer bitwidth, while maxseq represents the scope of seq/Int (and is always between 0 and (2^(bitwidth-1))-1).

Even though I do not know for sure without seeing your model, it seems that that is the case (namely, singleton constraints and bounds on integers together bound the number of solutions).

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right. Increasing the bitwidth fixed this issue. Thank you very much!